# Probability of a point being from the same distribution as sample

Tags: probability, distributions, p-value

I have a sample of two-dimensional points $\{\{x_1,y_1\}, \dotsc, \{x_n, y_n\}\}$, I've built a linear regression line, there seems to be a correlation between X and Y (Pearson's 0.662 if that matters).

Now what I need is to have a measure (p-value or something like that) of how likely an additional point $ \{x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}\}$ is from the same distribution as the sample. In other words, how "similar" a new point to the points from the sample is.

What are my options?

Sorry if my terminology is not adequate, I am new to all these. I'll provide additional details if needed

Comment: This depends also on the potential alternative distribution(s) that you consider. See the [likelihood ratio test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus It's hard to see how an LR test would apply.  This question concerns a prediction interval for a point.  An answer requires a model for the full joint distribution: the regression provides only part of that.

Comment: @whuber *"how likely an additional point ... is from the same distribution as the sample."* in this I see a clear direction indication that something like a p-value is desired. Or otherwise a prediction of the category (where previous measurements only relate to a single category): the (n+1)-th point is in the same distribution (category 1) or the (n+1)-th point is in a different distribution (category 2). For this we do not only need to know the distribution of category 1, but also the (potential) range of distributions of category 2.

Comment: Note that this question was originally asked on the *Mathematica* site:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278724/probability-of-a-point-being-from-the-same-distribution-as-sample.  I recommended that it be asked here to pin down the specifics of what kinds of "probabilities" could be addressed.

Comment: Will empirical distribution work? I.e. distribution that I estimate from n-points sample?

Also, an alternative idea - to estimate the probability of sample with added n+1'st point has the same (empirical) distribution as the original sample. This is sensitive to the actual n. If there is a way to normalize this to n that would do the job.

Comment: *"I've built a linear regression line"* Is this because $x$ is a controlled variable? You can compare the point $x_{n+1},y_{n+1}$ by regarding the joint distribution of $x$ and $y$, but you can also regard only the conditional distribution of $y$ given $x$ (e.g. the typical univariate outlier detection in linear regression). What sort of distribution does $x_i,y_i$ follow?

Comment: The reference to "empirical distribution" suggests you are looking for a non-parametric solution.  There is one.  Begin by defining a quantitative measure of how much any point might depart from the rest.  (A now-deleted answer proposes the Mahalanobis distance, for instance.)  Combine all $n+1$ data values.  Systematically remove each point and measure its distance relative to all the others. The p-value of this test is $k/(n+1)$ where $k$ counts the number of points (including the new one) whose distance equals or exceeds the distance of the new one. Is this the kind of solution you seek?